LVM Volume Group consumes most of my RAM
My machine always starts with all but 200-500Mb of RAM consumed and somehow it's having the only volume group active that's the problem.  No process is listed as using any significant amount of memory.

It's present when/if I can boot into the OS on that volume group.
It's present if I boot into a live ISO.
It's present if I replace the RAM sticks.  Changing the total RAM doesn't change how much RAM is free.
I cannot deactivate the volume group vgchange -an VGNAME hangs indefinitely.  pkill -9 fails to do anything.  Only powering off the machine works.
shutdown now will get as far as the powering off systemd task and then hang indefinitely.  Only powering off the machine works.
Disconnecting any physical volume of the volume group remedies the RAM issue because that forces the volume group to be inactive.

Although, as said above, I cannot start the machine with all physical volumes present and then deactivate the volume group.



My operating theory at this moment is the LVM system is in a bad state that's consuming almost all of my memory and the kernel is reserving a minimum amount.  The last LVM change I was able to successfully start was removing a large (1TB) LVM cache from a logical volume.  That process was taking forever and it was then that I noticed the increasing memory usage.  I was not able to stop the process and had to power off the system (point 4 above).  That said, there was some sort of problem before that I suspected was the lvm cache before, which was why I was trying to remove it.  I do not know how high the memory usage was before I started removing the cache.
What exactly is going on with my system and how can I remedy it?  Any suggestions on how to further investigate would also be deeply appreciated.  Please help.

update
I'm able to deactivate all but two of the logical volumes in the volume group.  The last two are a large bigdata volume and it's cache, bigcache, which I was trying to remove earlier.  Here's their output from lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cheez/bigdata
  LV Name                bigdata
  VG Name                cheez
  LV UUID                8CFDDm-2jCQ-v8r0-uLJZ-ttkh-OiFo-Qb9Xi8
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time cheez, 2018-04-28 00:54:11 +0000
  LV Cache pool name     bigcache_cpool
  LV Cache origin name   bigdata_corig
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                8.00 TiB
  Cache used blocks      99.89%
  Cache metadata blocks  1.53%
  Cache dirty blocks     100.00%
  Cache read hits/misses 69746 / 6529
  Cache wrt hits/misses  7366 / 90
  Cache demotions        0
  Cache promotions       0
  Current LE             2097152
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     131072
  Block device           254:19

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cheez/bigcache_cpool_meta0
  LV Name                bigcache_cpool_meta0
  VG Name                cheez
  LV UUID                8FkoNO-6JvF-bKge-6KOw-qFll-Nbnb-A235Fg
  LV Write Access        read only
  LV Creation host, time cheez, 2020-11-04 17:09:53 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                28.00 MiB
  Current LE             7
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:22


I tried re-running the previously interrupted lvconvert --uncache cheez/bigdata command.  The process was automatically killed a couple times for 'OOM' but I kept restarting it.  Eventually it finished and my RAM was cleared.  I tried rerunning the process again and it immediately consumed as much RAM as before until it finished.
Without any knowledge as to why or how, I'm concluding the interrupted lvconvert --uncache command was the culprit.  How it managed to take up so much memory when it wasn't running and persisting across reboots is beyond me.  As many kudos as I can give to whoever can explain that.
